# KeyPress event not firing on Edge for Enter Key in some cases?

Tags: javascript, keypress, microsoft-edge

I noticed that `keypress` event for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key doesn't always fire on MS Edge in some cases. I created the following examples on JSBin and JSFiddle, they behave differently.

On JSBin, keypress for <kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't fire on `document` until you put the focus into the `<input>`

https://jsbin.com/qoxadowepu/edit?html,js,output

On JSFiddle, keypress for <kbd>Enter</kbd> fires in both `<input>` and `document`.

http://jsfiddle.net/p4ohz8z9/1/

The behavior in my app is similar to the one in JSBin and it's unclear what's causing the keypress event for <kbd>Enter</kbd> not being triggered.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your problem, both event works for me in Edge and Chrome.

Comment: @DipenShah Would you mind trying navigate to the JSBin page and click outside of the input box and hit enter to see if it hows 13? It doesn't show 13 until I put focus in the input box. (I'm not yet able to get the Win10 anniversary update, so I'm not on the latest Edge)

Comment: @lousi.luo Try using "keydown" instead of "KeyPress".

Comment: @DipenShah Yea, that's fine as a workaround, though I want to understand if people has seen this and knows what's causing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This no longer happens in EdgeHTML 14.14393 after the Win10 Anniversary Update.